Will manual memory allocation in .Net Framework 2.0?
I am C# Winform beginner Developer.
My current work is to create a class and read text file.
namespace test
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        Txt_File_Data txt;

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void test_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var filePath = string.Empty;

            using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
                openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
                openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
                openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
                }
            }

            txt = new Txt_File_Data(filePath);
        }

        private void test_Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Memory Allocation");
        }
    }
}

Currently, we are using a method of initializing using null.
If Winform says it has a Clear button, is there a way to manually release memory? I don't want to use a garbage collector, and I'm wondering if the package exists or ohters. Like 0SuperComicLib.LowLevel in .Net Framework 4.6.1

"I don't want to use a garbage collector" - then you've picked the wrong language/framework to be working in. Also, you really shouldn't be working with .NET Framework 2 either - it's archaic, and long out of support.

Since you seem to be working with files you should probably implement the dispose pattern. This is for handling non-memory resources. To handle memory you are more or less stuck with the GC, but that should not be a problem unless you are doing something very memory intensive.

Now working on 2.0, moving on to 4.8 soon. But I was wondering if there was a way to solve it in 2.0, so I posted it. thanks.

You didn't describe any kind of problem so it's impossible to offer any solution. If you want to dispose expensive objects, you use their .Dispose() method, not set them to null. Garbage collection doesn't waste memory, quite the opposite. It prevents the kinds of leaks you had in C or C++ when you forgot to delete an object. With GC, orphaned objects are deleted automatically after a while. As for 2.0, it reached End Of Life in 2011, 13 years ago. "soon" passed a long time ago

If you want to conserve memory, reuse buffers eg through the ArrayPool provided through the System.Buffers NuGet package for .NET Framework  4.5 and later. There's no version for .NET Framework 2.0 because that version had reached EOL 5 years before System.Buffers was released

It is possible to use pointers in unsafe code blocks in c#. As I remember this was already available in .net fw 2.0 too. Using pointers you can manage your memory (at least a part of it) yourself without GC.
